# How to use Response->withJson inside PHP Slim 3 Route Group?

Tags: php, rest, grouping, httpresponse, slim

I am trying to get $response inside individual routes grouped by common URL. In individual routes, without grouping them, I just do this, and it works :

```
$app->get('/news', function($req, $resp) use ($app) {
      return $resp->withJson([ 
         "someProp" => $someValue,
       ])->withStatus(200);
}
```

But when I group my routes, like the ones which belongs to ADMIN section, I do not know how to get the Request & Response instances, like this:

```
$app->group('/admin' function() {
     $this->get('/dashboard', function(Request $req, Response $resp) {
         return $resp->withJson(["property" => $someValue]);
});
});
```

App crashes when I use $resp, but if for example, I change it to a simple "**echo**" it returns plain text, showing me that it may not be taking the Response Object correctly.

I had imported the correct libraries:

> use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
>
> use\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

And I get some error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Closure::{closure}() must be
> an instance of Request, instance of Slim\App given

I have followed all the documentation page, but not working at all...

Answer (score 0):

The main and big problem, had nothing to do with Request - Response. The correct app structure to use, working with **Slim Framework ^3.0** when you have to group some routes, is the following:

```
// First inject this
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->group('/admin', function() use ($app){


    $app->get('/secciones/activas', function ( Request $request, Response $response ){
    //return response here

    return $response->withJson(['someProp' => $pDOResult ]);

})
});
```

If you look at this line:

> return $response->withJson(['someProp' => $pDOResult ]);

I was passing a Result **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC** set, and there was something wrong with charset configurations, that database data contains special characters that were crashing the JSON parser, so I fixed it with this line, inmediately after **$db->connect();**

```
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
```